# How do I modify POST request in Account.jsx file?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am working on a personal project Employee Management System and am stuck on sending POST request. The project is using MERN (MongoDB, nodejs, and reactjs). The following is the project link https://github.com/Mbicha/employee_management_system, and [Image showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LT1c.png)

Codes are as follows:

```
Account.jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import http from "../http-common";

const Account = () => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        first_name: "", last_name: "", email: "", phone: "", password: ""
    });

    const handleFormChange = (event) => {
        setFormData(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        }));
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        try {
            const options = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            };
            await http.post('/user', formData, options);
            console.log("Saved");
            event.target.reset();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
                <form className="flex flex-col items-center rounded-lg shadow-md p-2 w-full sm:w-2/3 md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/3">
                    <h1 className="text-center text-green-700 text-2xl mb-4">Account</h1>

                    <input className="border-b-2 border-gray-400 w-4/5 p-2 mb-4 focus:outline-none focus:border-green-700" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name='first_name' onChange={handleFormChange}/>

                    <input className="border-b-2 border-gray-400 w-4/5 p-2 mb-4 focus:outline-none focus:border-green-700" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name='last_name' onChange={handleFormChange}/>

                    <input className="border-b-2 border-gray-400 w-4/5 p-2 mb-4 focus:outline-none focus:border-green-700" type="email" placeholder="Email" name='email' onChange={handleFormChange}/>

                    <input className="border-b-2 border-gray-400 w-4/5 p-2 mb-4 focus:outline-none focus:border-green-700" type="text" placeholder="Phone" name='phone' onChange={handleFormChange}/>

                    <input className="border-b-2 border-gray-400 w-4/5 p-2 mb-4 focus:outline-none focus:border-green-700" type="password" placeholder="Password" name='password' onChange={handleFormChange}/>

                    <button className="bg-green-700 hover:bg-green-600 text-white font-bold p-2 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline w-4/5 mb-4" type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>Register</button>
                    <span>Already have an account? <Link to='/'>Login</Link></span>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Account;

http-common.js

import axios from "axios";

    export default axios.create({
        baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/api",
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        }
    });

server.js

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookie = require('cookie-parser');
require('./config/db.config');

const auth = require('./routes/route_auth');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookie());

//routes
app.use('/api/user', auth);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on ${PORT}`);
});

route_auth.js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const user = require("../controllers/auth");

router.post('/', user.register);

module.exports = router;

auth.js // controller
const user = require("../models/user");
const utils = require("../utils");

exports.register = async(req, res) => {

    try {
        const hashed = utils.hashPassword(req.body.password, 10);
        const newUser = new user({
            first_name: req.body.first_name,
            last_name: req.body.last_name,
            email: req.body.email,
            phone: req.body.phone,
            password: hashed
        });
        await newUser.save();
        res.status(201).json(newUser);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).send({ error:error });
    }
}

// All users
exports.getUsers = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const users = await user.find({});
        res.send({ users })
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send({err: err});
    }
};

// User by id
module.exports.getUserById = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await user.findById(req.params.id);
        res.send({ user });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).send({ message: `User is not found` });
    }
}

user.js // model
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const user = new Schema({
    first_name: {type: String, required: true},
    last_name: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    phone: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("user", user);

db.config.js

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/employees_db"

// Allow Promises
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
// Connection
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology:true  });
// Validation
mongoose.connection
  .once('open', () => console.log('Connected to the database!'))
  .on('error', err => console.log('Error with the database!', err));
  
utils.js

const bycrypt = require('bcrypt');

// Hash Method
const hashPassword = (password, rounds) => {
    const salt = bycrypt.genSaltSync(rounds);
    const hashedPassword = bycrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
    return hashedPassword;
}
```

Error is in occurring in Account.jsx when I send a data to the database "http://localhost:5000/api/user 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Please include relevant code, config, and errors in the question, formatted properly.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I have added relevant codes

Comment: I have fixed the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404 Error code means that there is no endpoint which is related to `/api/user`.

```
// In the server.js

//routes

app.use('/api/user', auth);

// routes/route_auth.js

router.post('/', user.register);
```

I think your correct endpoint path is /api/user/ <- add trailing slash